# emitting data using SocketIO in a node app across routes/pages

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

A form in the index.html will make a `post` request to the `/history` route and fetch the data from the MongoDB database:

server.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/history', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/history.html');
});

app.post("/history", (req, res)=> {
    // fetch data from database
    io.emit('data-history', data)
}
```

In the history.js:

```js
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
io.on('data-history', (data) => {
  // render data to the page
}
```

Somehow the data cannot be transferred from server.js to history.js. I am aware that the socket got disconnected when I am switching pages,

Comment: Please describe in more detail exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  What exactly are you trying to do and what exactly is the problem you have with the code you show?

Comment: I am trying to fetch data from the database on the server.js first, then it will load a new page and render the data. The data-fetching part is fine, but I am having trouble transferring the data from the server to the front end.

Comment: Is the POST to `/history` coming from a browser form submission or from an Ajax call in the web page?  If from a form submission, your structure can never work because the browser expects a response from the POST that it will display.  If from Ajax, then why not just send the data back as a response to the Ajax call?